# Unable to install Android Kenai plugin on Netbeans 6.8

Tags: netbeans

I am currently using JDK 1.6.0_30 with JRE 1.6.0_30 . I want to develop android applications on Netbeans using nbandroid plugin proviede by Project kenai. I have added the Plugin to my plugins list . But whenever i try to install it , I get the Following error :

The following plugins are not updated :

```
Swing Layout Extensions integration version >= 1.13.1 
but only 1.10.1.103 was found.  
JPDA Debugger API version >= 2.27.1 but only 2.23.1 was found.  
Classpath APIs version >= 1.25.1 but only 1.22.1 was found.  
Javac API Wrapper  version >= 0.13.1.1 but only 0.11.1.1 was found.  
External Execution Support version >= 1.21.1 but only 1.18.1 was found.  
Java Source  version >= 0.60.1.10.8.4 but only 0.52.2.8.8.2 was found.  
Options Dialog and SPI  version >= 1.18.1 but only 1.16.2 was found.  
Debugger Core - UI  version >= 2.23.1 but only 2.19.1 was found.  
Explorer & Property Sheet API version >= 6.28.1 but only 6.22.2.1 was found.  
I/O APIs version >= 1.23.1 but only 1.20.1 was found.  
Datasystems API Version >= 7.16.1 but only 7.10.1 was found.  
Nodes API Version >= 7.16.1 but only 7.12.1.1 was found.  
Text API Version >= 6.30.1 but only 6.27.1 was found.  
org.openide.util.lookup Version 8.3.1.   
Some plugins not installed to avoid potential installation problems.
```

I have no idea where to update and what to update for all these  plugins. 
And i am using netbeans 6.8 . Please do not suggest eclipse for development , as i want to try with netbeans only.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade to at least NetBeans 6.9. We dropped compatibility with 6.8 a while ago when there were two newer releases available (6.9 and 7.0) and There is third one out already 7.1.

I have updated http://www.nbandroid.org/p/installation.html page.

-Radim